# Error: MountEmulatedStorage()

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-studio, samsung-mobile

I'm working on a webapp, which do a login on a server and get some data back. Everything was fine until yesterday evening. Now the app does nothing. The startpage is loaded with the buttons and the inputs, but if I klikk on one nothing happened. I refused my actual changes but the errors don't vanish. 
Was someone in a similar situation? I started AS, my MAC and my S5 new, but nothing worked.

The errors are:

```
E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
E/Zygote: v2
E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a custom ExceptionHandler? it is possible that you are not printing the stackTrace to the Log and then a simple Crash like ClassCastException will leave you hanging in the air... with only The Error you have discribed